# Regex splitting mathematical expression after operators and look for a negative number

Tags: java, regex

Is there someway to split an expression according to operators and negative numbers?

if I have a string `"2+-2"`, I want the `-2` to be the object in my array?

```
    String exp = "2+-2";
    String[] temp = new String[exp.length()];
    temp =exp.split("(?<=[-+*/^])|(?=[-+*/^])");
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    LinkedList <String>list= new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
        String s = temp[i]+"";
        if(s.equals("-")) {
           while(!stack.isEmpty())
           {
              String tkn=stack.pop();
              if(tkn.equals("*")|| tkn.equals("/") || tkn.equals("+")||tkn.equals("-")||tkn.equals("^"))
                  list.add(tkn);
              else{
                  stack.push(tkn);
                  break;
              }
           }
           stack.push(s);
. . . for every operator . . .
```

Comment: doesnt work, output:[2, +, -, 2] :/

Comment: Maybe [`(?<=(?<=\d)[-+*\/^])|(?=[-+*\/^])`](https://regex101.com/r/lM3cM6/1)?

Comment: Not with a regular expression. You need a parser. You might get something trivial working for trivial expressions, but the moment you need parentheses or precedence you will have to throw it all away and start again. Do it right first time.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

This regex will:

- Find all the numbers in a math equation
- Capture all numbers and return them as an array
- Capture the positive or negative sign if included on a number

Regex

```
(?:(?<=[-+/*^]|^)[-+])?\d+(?:[.]\d+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Sample Java Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(?:(?<=[-+/*^])[-+]?)\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Text**

```
1+1
2.1+-2.2
3.1+3.2
4.1--4.2
5.1-+5.2
-6.1--6.2
7.1-7.2
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 1
[2] => 2.1
[3] => -2.2
[4] => 3.1
[5] => 3.2
[6] => 4.1
[7] => -4.2
[8] => 5.1
[9] => +5.2
[10] => 6.1
[11] => -6.2
[12] => 7.1
[13] => 7.2
```

**Online Java Validator**

http://fiddle.re/b2w5wa

## Extra

In your original question you eluded to only being interested in the second value. If that is the case then this is the regex for you

```
(?:(?<=[-+/*^])[-+]?)\d+(?:[.]\d+)?
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0] => 1
[1] => -2.2
[2] => 3.2
[3] => -4.2
[4] => +5.2
[5] => 6.1
[6] => -6.2
[7] => 7.2
```

Comment: an easy example. if I have "2+-2" as expression
I want the array to be [2, -2, +]

Comment: or if I have 2+4*-8-2 as an expression i want it to split it to
[2,4,-8,*,+,2,-]

@Denomales

Comment: or the first array to [2,+,4,*,-8,-,2]
So if a negative sign '-' comes first in the expression or after an operator we'll know that its a negative number!